# How to use cssselect and lxml to get option values from select drop down?

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

I want to get/scrape data from a select dropdown box using lxml and cssselect.

I have tried a few things and searched the web with no luck so far:

so the following or similar code is on a page I am scraping:

```
<select id="attribute501" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[501]">
<option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
<option value="33">5</option>
<option value="31">10</option>
</select>
```

using the following cssselect statement:

```
css_sel_price_dd = 'html body.catalog-product-view div.wrapper div.page div.main-container div.main div.col-main div.product-view div.product-essential form div.product-shop select'


pack_size_obj = root.cssselect(css_sel_price_dd)
print 'This strain has a drop down select box for different pack sizes: '
print pack_size_obj
pack_size = pack_size_obj[0].text_content().encode('utf-8').strip()
print 'Pack Size: ' + pack_size
```

Yields the following result:

```
This strain has a drop down select box for different pack sizes: 
[<SelectElement 10e77d590 name='super_attribute[501]'>]
Pack Size: Choose an Option...
```

but so far I am unable to get access to the the text values from the other option, i.e. 5 and 10 from

```
<option value="33">5</option>
<option value="31">10</option>
```

- I have tried adding option to the css path and various things but can't seem to guess the syntax and can't find anything online...

Still not working - here is actual code snippet with url etc.

```
import lxml.html
import requests
import csv


user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17'}
# Open a session 
s = requests.session()

s.get('http://www.seedsman.com/en/cannabis-seeds', headers = user_agent)

css_sel_price_dd = '.product-shop select option'

open_seed_url = 'http://www.seedsman.com/en/amsterdam-mist-feminised-seeds'
print 'From the following URL: ' + open_seed_url

r = s.get(open_seed_url, headers = user_agent)
r_encoding = r.encoding
print 'encoding type of r:'
print r_encoding

myhtml = r.text # gives us a unicode string work with unicode and encode at the end when have piece of data we want

print myhtml.encode('utf-8')

root = lxml.html.fromstring(myhtml)

pack_size_obj = root.cssselect(css_sel_price_dd)
print pack_size_obj
for opt in pack_size_obj:
    print '{0} : {1}'.format(opt.get('value'), opt.text)
```

Hopefully somebody can see what is going wrong?

returns:

```
From the following URL: http://www.seedsman.com/en/amsterdam-mist-feminised-seeds
encoding type of r: UTF-8
** HTML removed for brevity ** 
[<Element option at 0x1108dcbf0>] 
None : Choose an Option... 
[Finished in 3.9s]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `option` to your selector, and then you will get a list of option elements. Look at this sample snippet, only the html is simplified a bit:

```
src_html = """
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <select id="attribute501" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[501]">
                <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
                <option value="33">5</option>
                <option value="31">10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""
root = html.fromstring(src_html)

css_sel_price_dd = 'html body div select option'
pack_size_obj = root.cssselect(css_sel_price_dd)
for opt in pack_size_obj:
    print '{0} : {1}'.format(opt.get('value'), opt.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am using python 2.7 on osx and can't get this to work?! I get an error on final line - the error claims to be indentation error but this isn't the case. Should the above code work with my version of python?

Comment: Also when i print the list css_sel_price_dd after modifying the my cssselect code (by adding option) - I still get a list of one item, which is why i thought that wasn't working originally before i asked the question. So can you explain what is happening assuming above is working, thanks!!

Comment: there should be no indentation error, check if you pasted it correctly. as for the results, there is probably an error in your selector, and you're finding something else than you're searching for. if you could post the url to that page, I could verify it.

Comment: I can get above to work as is with minor addition of lxml.html.fromsting(src_html) - so can confirm your answer is correct not sure what's going wrong for me...

Comment: by using the FirePath FireBug extension in FireFox, evaluating even this simple selector: `.product-shop select option`   finds 3 option elements, I guess it should work, the only possibility is that the html where you are searching does not contain that data actually.

Comment: I am still having problems - I have added my actual code to above - perhaps you could have another look as this is confusing the hell out of me... I cannot select the select element on the actual page - still getting a list of one object... See my additional code above p p please! @andrean!

Comment: OK - I see that the code I want to grab is written in with javascript hence when i access the raw html the info is not actually in the html! So can't get it using lxml - I guess will write a regular expression to extract from javascript - thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `xpath`

```
options = root.xpath("//select[@id='attribute501']/option")
option_text = [option.text for option in options]
```

**OR**

```
options = root.xpath("//select[@id='attribute501']/option/text()")
```